# Clean negative time

Tags: sql, time, negative-number

I am running a project and in data entries (given) I found negative time for example started_at was later than ended_at (24h). I have to clean the data in order to analyse it and I wonder how to deal with it. Do I have to assume that was a wrong entry from the system and fix them (put them the other way around)? Or delete these rows? How do I deal with this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Based on the information in your post, I don't see that the SO community can give you a helpful answer. If it were me, I would want to understand how it was possible that the data integrity was compromised. Does the system not validate the data? Did the user who entered the data make the same mistake consistently? How will the data be used? What's the implication of correcting the data?

Comment: How is anyone expected to know what business rules to apply to clean up your data? If you define the business rules then someone may be able to help with how to apply them

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing more about where the data came from and what it means.

Comment: It is a case study from Google data analytics professional certificate. It is a fictional project however the data is given to practise and analyse.

Comment: I suggest to practice and analyze.  As far as I have understood you you have already analyze it. Now practice what you learn it is the best option. Because, if it is a practice, then there is no wrong way to do it.

Comment: Sometimes events represented by started_at and ended cross day boundaries into the next day. You need to consider what sort of events these are and if these are likely to go over midnight, or even to multiple days. Then you need to consider the purpose of your query. If you need exact data your database design may not provide it